# How to access Textencoder as a global instead of importing it from the util package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using Node v18.0.0 with TypeScript and it seems that the [`TextEncoder` class is a global](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/globals.html#textencoder).

Unfortunately this code `const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();` is invalid because it doesn't know about the class. I will have to import the util package to make it work, otherwise I get the error

> Cannot find name 'TextEncoder'. Did you mean 'textEncoder'?ts(2552)

I'm using the packages `"@types/node": "17.0.23"` and `"typescript": "4.6.3"`. The tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [ "esnext" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2019"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./build"
  ]
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this? Do I have to use some additional packages or modify my TS configuration?

Please let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an inconsistency (at least) between the Node.js documentation (and runtime) and the `@types/node` package in DefinitelyTyped. This issue is very similar to [this one with `URL`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19799), which has since been fixed by adding a `global` declaration in `url.d.ts`. It may be worth opening an issue (and doing a PR).

As you say, `TextEncoder` is definitely a global (both the documentation and a quick test tell us that), but `@types/node/globals.d.ts` doesn't have it. `@types/node/utils.d.ts` does have it (as you indicated), and even has the comment *"The `TextEncoder` class is also available on the global object."* but...it's not (unlike `URL`, which [now] is).

If the code you're writing is Node.js-specific, I'd just do the import and not worry about it.

But if the code you're writing is supposed to target both Node.js and browsers, that's obviously not an option. One workaround mentioned in the `URL` issue thread is to add `"dom"` to your `lib` config setting, but that means all the DOM stuff is added to your global namespace.

Alternatively, until/unless the types are updated, you can declare the global yourself. In the root of your project:

`whatever.d.ts`:

```typescript
import { TextEncoder as _TextEncoder } from "node:util";

declare global {
    var TextEncoder: typeof _TextEncoder;
}
```

You don't get useful popup information when you do `new TextEncoder(`, but it does work, and you do get useful information for its methods etc.

Comment: adding `dom` to the `lib` config setting helped :) But yes, I'm targeting Node and browsers so I think I will have to open an issue